# Free-Form Date Picker - like RTM

Tags: javascript, ajax, dhtml

I'm looking for a way to have a textbox that allows users to type in a date in any format and turns around and formats that date in a 'mm/dd/yyyy' format.  So the user could type in "Today" and it would turn the date as 02/24/2009 or they could type in Wednesday Feb 24 and formatting would automatically pick up.  Remember the Milk does this (but I believe server side).  This is asp.net so I could do via ajax web service call but I would prefer to do this via Javascript.  I'm looking for a general technique or existing library to help with this.

Comment: Why'd you make this community wiki? You don't get Reputation for that.

Comment: In case someone wanted to edit my stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://www.datejs.com/