# user-friendly time entry

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

In my project (based on php/mysql/jquery ) i need the user to enter time.
But it seems very annoying to enter the time in strict formats like
06:00 PM
or 
14:00

So i want to give the user freedom to enter time in a very friendly way like
6 pm, 11am etc
or
14
which will then be converted internally into a strict time format for further processing.
Can anybody suggest me any good plugin . If no plugins are there please suggest me how to approach.

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476822/jquery-time-picker

Comment: Also similiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579354/whats-the-best-approach-to-get-date-time-input-from-the-user

Comment: And similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582146/free-form-date-picker-like-rtm/582189#582189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I tend to do for date and/or time fields is let the user enter it in whatever format they like, then format it back to a "universal" particular format on blur of the field. [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is incredibly handy for both the parsing and the formatting.

Something like

```
$('.timeboxme').blur(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var theDate = Date.parse($el.val());
    if(theDate) {
        $el.val(theDate.toString("HH:mm"));
    } else {
        //it didn't appear to be a valid date/time, tell the user
    }
});
```

As a bonus, if you use date.js, you get some fancy tricks you can tell the user about, like "+3 hours" or "last hour" :-)

Comment: Date.js looks perfect :) . Thanks.

Comment: No worries. It won't handle just plain old 14 though (it thinks you mean the day of the month), so you might want to fenurgle together a regexp or something to check if it's just a number and handle that case specially. Apart from that, date.js is an awesome piece of kit

Answer (score 3):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) is very close to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

here's an interesting jquery plugin i found recently

http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

---

If you dont wan't to use a jquery plugin my best recommendation would be to use select boxes

3 selects would do it

[hour][minute][ampm]

or even

[hour][minute]

if you went the 24hr route

---

to me allowing someone to enter '14' into a text to the user

Comment: yes i know there are several plugins out there .. but i dont want to go for those fancy but irritating time entry plugins.
In fact i am using this one which is simple yet friendly
http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/

But i want to integrate the feature i explained avove (ie. allow time like 6pm, 13 etc )